# Load testing with Python's requests?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I want to use the Python requests library to send many HTTP requests at the same time, as I'm load testing my server. Is there an easy way to go about this?

**EDIT:** For clarification, I know how to send a request with requests. What I don't know is how to send another request before awaiting the response.

Comment: Sure you don't want to try [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/ab.html) before reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Due to heavy customization of the requests, I don't think ab would do the job.

Comment: Uhm, ab can fire custom requests as well. Is it safe to assume then, that each request would have to carry individual payload?

Comment: @DaSourcerer Yes, I'm sending different payloads

Comment: https://github.com/loads exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference in case anyone else ends up having the same issue: I ended up using the Threading library, and simply creating a few hundred threads, each of these sending an HTTP request.

It was much simpler than it appeared. A good example that made it fairly clear was [here](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/). Specifically, this code was a great help:

```
import threading

def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    print 'Worker: %s' % num
    return

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```